# Efficient method to identify a filenames extension when the non-extension name is known

Tags: perl

```
    my $cover="/******/gamebooks/Accounts/$Author/MyBooks/$Book/images/cover/cover.jpg";
if(-e $cover){
    $cover=$uri->encode("https://fightingfantasy.net/gamebooks/Accounts/$Author/MyBooks/$Book/images/cover/cover.jpg");
}
else{
    # print "$cover not found";
    $cover="$perl_scriptlocation/resources/images/beholder.jpg";
}
```

This is my code at the moment - the directory will have 1 file in it named cover. -the extension will be any valid graphical format commonly displayed by browsers.  I *could* do a directory listing, strip out the results containing the parent and child nodes and use the remaining result but it seems an extremely verbose way of doing it... does anyone have a quicker method to do this?  I imagine wildcards are in use somehow...  Many thanks.

For those interested (thanks to the 1st answer) my final solution isthis:

```
    my $coverbase="/******/gamebooks/Accounts/$Author/MyBooks/$Book/images/cover/cover";
    my $cover = glob qq("${coverbase}.*");

    if(-e $cover){
        $cover=~/.*\/(.*)/i;
        $coverfile=$1;
        $cover=$uri->encode("https://fightingfantasy.net/gamebooks/Accounts/$Author/MyBooks/$Book/images/cover/$coverfile");
    }
    else{
        # print "$cover not found";
        $cover="$perl_scriptlocation/resources/images/beholder.jpg";
    }
```

Which is a lot more satisfying than the only option I had before I knew about glob many thanks (yes I know it could be stripped by 2 or 3 lines still with some elegance but I don't have that yet!)

Comment: Note: `glob` in scalar context **iterates over the entry list**.   So if this code is in a loop of some sort every next time it will return the _next file_, until there are no more at which point it returns `undef`.  That's a feature but you need to be careful.  In a list context (when assigned to an array for example) it simply returns all entries.

Comment: `my $cover = glob qq("${coverbase}.*");` should be `my ($cover) = glob qq("${coverbase}.*");`. /// `if(-e $cover){` is wrong; `$cover` is undefined if the glob didn't match. It should be `if(defined($cover)){`.  ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings`.

Comment: It's not in a loop thankfully only needed once in the script.  I'll have a think about the undef - for now it seems to work fine even when it is undef?  Yeah strict and warnings - ummmm my entire site would break under those circumstances atm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand your question. But I assume you have the basename (e.g. "picture") and want to have the name with extension assuming that such a file exists (e.g. "picture.jpg", "picture.png" ..).  In this case `glob` would help:

```
  my ($file) = glob("$basename.*") or die "no such file exists";
```

Comment: exactly what I'm looing for I think - I will try it

Comment: stuff it I'll leave the comment as 'struggling with glob it doesn;t seem to like spaces in pathname' lol

Comment: @Beeblbrox  The `glob` indeed can't do spaces -- if you have that around use [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html). Add `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob';` at the top and `glob` will honor spaces in names.

Comment: This scalar context can be dangerous for unwary since it iterates, and very globally.  Perhaps add a note to that effect?

Comment: uh - I've sorted it?  Many thanks - a bit of reading about glob covers the spaces issue - but any other dangers I need to know about welcome... nothnig is in there that is user defined and not already 'safe' afaik

Comment: @Beeblbrox By "_dangerous_" (in my comment above) I meant that if you don't know about this context it may (quietly) do things other than expected.  So if you were to say `if (my $f = glob ...) { ... }` and that is in a loop of some sort, the code _will not_ check every time for that one file you have, but it will return its name the first time and then an `undef` the next time (unless there are actually yet more files, in which case it will return those names one by one...).

Comment: Don't call `glob` in scalar context without exhausting the iterator! Fixed.